# Delete QNetworkReply *reply cause SIGSEGV outside of the code?

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I wrote a simple program to automate the process setting the router. After a check, I find a pointer need to be `delete` (`QNetworkReply *reply` in `replyFinish()`)and do the job, but after that the program crash and Qt show it stopped in some assembly code :(

So my questions are:

1. Are there any common practices to handle situation like that (Qt
   show the program stopped in some assembly code)
2. What did I do wrong when delete a pointer which isn't used anymore?
       (pretty sure about that)

Here is the code:

```
#ifndef HTTPGETTER_H
#define HTTPGETTER_H
class QNetworkAccessManager;
class QNetworkReply;
class QNetworkRequest;
class QAuthenticator;
#include <QObject>

class httpGetter : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *nam;
public:
    explicit httpGetter(QObject *parent=0);
    ~httpGetter();
public slots:
    void replyFinish(QNetworkReply* reply);
    void onAuthen(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*);
};
```

implements

```
#include "httpgetter.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QAuthenticator>
#include <QDebug>
httpGetter::httpGetter(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    QObject::connect(nam,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(replyFinish(QNetworkReply*)));
    QObject::connect(nam,SIGNAL(authenticationRequired(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)),this,SLOT(onAuthen(QNetworkReply*,QAuthenticator*)));

    QUrl url("http://192.168.1.1");
    QNetworkReply *reply= nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));


}
httpGetter::~httpGetter(){
    delete nam;
}
void httpGetter::replyFinish(QNetworkReply *reply)
{
    if (reply==NULL) {
        qDebug() << "NULL reply";
        return;
    }

    QVariant statusCode = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);

    qDebug() << statusCode.toString();

    if (reply->error()==QNetworkReply::NoError) {
        qDebug() << "NICE reply";
        QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();
        QString answer = QString(bytes);
        qDebug()<< answer;
    }

    else {
        qDebug() << "reply error";
    }

    //delete reply; ==> delele cause sigsegv, if don't the program run like a     while(true)
    //reply == NULL;

}

void httpGetter::onAuthen(QNetworkReply* rep,QAuthenticator* auth)
{
    if ( rep==NULL || auth == NULL) {
        qDebug()<< "reply or authentication pointer is null";
        return;
    }

    qDebug()<< rep->readAll();
    auth->setUser("rolan");
    auth->setPassword("123456");
}
```

main

```
#include <QtCore/QCoreApplication>
#include "httpgetter.h"


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    httpGetter abc;




    return a.exec();
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html):

> **Note**: After the request has finished, it is the responsibility of the
>   user to delete the `QNetworkReply` object at an appropriate time. Do not
>   directly delete it inside the slot connected to `finished()`. You can
>   use the `deleteLater()` function.

Also, since

```
nam = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
```

creates a new `QNetworkAccessManager` with `this` as its parent, and `QObject`'s destructor will automatically delete all of its children, your `delete nam;` in `httpGetter`'s destructor is unnecessary and will end up causing a double delete.

Comment: It seems we posted the "same answer" almost at the same time. Yours was first, so I'll remove mine and leave this comment stating that this answer is correct, in my opinion.

Comment: Hi, I followed [**this guide**](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Creating_an_HTTP_network_request_in_Qt). Maybe it's outdated. Before mark this question's answered, can you tell me are there any common practices to handle the situation: Qt stopped in some assembly code?

Comment: PS: Kudo to you @mhcuervo; you're very nice :)

Comment: BTW, can you explain why even i call `reply->close()` the output console still "hang" and not exit the program (display: `press enter to continue...`)